# 'sort' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++

Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
    void sort_priorities( )
    {
        std::sort( _priorities.begin( ),
            _priorities.end( ),
            [ ]( auto &first, auto &sec ) -> bool
            {
                return first.first < sec.first;
            } );
    }

    draw_manager( ) = default;
    void init( );
};
```

The error I get is:

> 'sort': is not a member of 'std' (compiling source file rendering\Wrapper\Implementation\D3D9Manager.cpp)

Comment: Please create a [mre], including the headers you include.

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`? Also what compiler?

Comment: I am voting to close. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In order to have access to sort, you need to include algorithm. Add it to your included headers with

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: wait for OP to clarify the doubts then answer the question

Comment: It's fine.  He answered a question many C++ noobs have (like myself).  His answer is helpful.

Comment: It seems like my answer is actually a duplicate. Would best practice be for me to delete my answer?

Comment: No, don't worry about duplicates.  They work themselves out in the end.

Comment: The reason being if OP has already included the header, this answer doesn't hold good.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312312/answering-a-question-after-it-has-been-flagged-as-a-potential-duplicate-bad-for

Comment: IMO, don't worry about whether a question is a duplicate, if you know the answer then go ahead and answer it. At some point, you'll recognize questions as having been answered, in which case, vote to close it if you can.

Comment: A good strategy for “unclear” questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315370/a-good-strategy-for-unclear-questions

Comment: The thing with C++ is with the exception of stuff added in C++17 or 20, pretty much everything has been answered. The hard part is finding the duplicate.